# Multi select grid not working

Tags: grid, extjs4, multi-select

I have a grid panel in ExtJS 4 with the following features:

```
extend : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
multiSelect: true,
alias : 'widget.negativeMoviesView',
frame : true,
autoScroll : true,
height: 690,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
store : 'NegativeMovieStore',
columns : [{
            header : 'Name',
            dataIndex : 'name',
            flex : 1
}]
```

multiSelect is set to true, and if I check in firebug it is in fact true and the selectionMode is MULTI, however it only allows me to select one row at a time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you selecting rows? singe click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As sha pointed out. The multiSelect option only enables the grid to have multiple selections by making use of the Shift or Ctrl keys to select a batch or add to the selection in the same way a native application allows.

If you are looking for single click to add/remove from the selection you can use the simpleSelect or selModel property to achieve this.

This will enable single click to add/remove from the selection

```
simpleSelect: true
```

This will render an extra column which will let you check the rows you wish to select.

```
selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel')
```

Answer (score 1):

[Demo for ExtJs 4.0](http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-4-0-7-grid-multiselect)

[Demo for ExtJs 4.1](http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-4-1-1-grid-multiselect)